# I want my title and my navigation bar to be at the same border-bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, title

I've just started learning HTML and CSS, therefore I don't know much. I have checked the other questions and tried the answers which was given but none of them worked for me. I want my title and my navigation bar at the same border-bottom. I've tried so many methods and I don't know what to do next.

This is my html;

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
    <nav id="nav01"></nav>
    <h1 class="padding">hardalname</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <footer id="foot01"></footer>
    </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my CSS;

```
body {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #696969;
    padding: 3px;
}

#main {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    border-bottom: 1px double darkred;
    color: darkred;
    font-size: 30px;
}


h1.padding {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}


ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;

}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;

}

ul#menu li a {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
    border-radius; 4px 4px 0 0;

}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

And this is the navigation bar that I'm using;

```
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>hardalname</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='about.html'>hakkımda</a></li>" +
"</ul>";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #696969;
  padding: 3px;
}
#main {
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  border-bottom: 1px double darkred;
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 30px;
}
h1.padding {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
  border-radius;
  4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <nav id="nav01">
      <ul id='menu'>
        <li><a href='index.html'>hardalname</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='about.html'>hakkımda</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="padding">hardalname</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <footer id="foot01"></footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean of `same border-bottom`?

Comment: I mean the line, which is under my title, that goes until the right end of the page.

Comment: I just copy/pasted you code on my editor and run the page and everything is great and the line goes until right end of the page, as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule that adds the border to your nav:

```
#nav01{
    border-bottom: 1px double darkred; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cckL62bp/)

Comment: Yeah, but I want them to be at the same border. Title on the left of the page, navigation on the right.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much! Can you explain me the way please?